# How to alter view to combine rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, multiple-columns, sql-server-2019

I am trying to create a view from this table:

[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbBJx.png)

I use the following code to make the view:

```
CREATE VIEW Zrad_vw_CSR
AS
SELECT usertype, usercode, 
    custcode, MAX(fromdate) AS "Recent",
    CASE WHEN usertype = 1 THEN 'Sales Rep' END AS Salesrep,
    CASE WHEN usertype = 0 THEN 'CSR' END AS CSR
FROM Original Table
GROUP BY usercode, custcode, usertype
```

This is the output of the view:

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdEL1.png)

I used the following code to alter the view:

```
ALTER VIEW Zrad_vw_CSR AS 
SELECT custcode,
       MIN(Salesrep) Salesrep,
       MIN(CSR) CSR
FROM Zrad_vw_CSR
GROUP BY custcode, Salesrep, CSR;
```

However I got the following error:

```
View or function 'Zrad_vw_CSR' contains a self-reference. Views or functions cannot reference themselves directly or indirectly.
```

I am trying to get the output to look like this:

[Preferred Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQFcQ.png)

The reason why I want to the output to look like this is because the CSR and Salesrep columns share the same custcode. I would like to combine all the custcode so that the custcode and corresponding CSR and Salesrep code are in one row. Would appreciate any help. I am using Microsoft server management studio 18

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, you can't have a `VIEW` `SELECT` from itself.

Comment: I was grouping Salesrep and CSR and aggregating them because of this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171869/sql-server-i-need-to-combine-multiple-rows-into-one-row-with-different-column) and was trying to replicate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view text my be arranged thus

```
ALTER VIEW Zrad_vw_CSR AS 
SELECT custcode,
       MIN(Salesrep) Salesrep,
       MIN(CSR) CSR
FROM
 (
   SELECT usertype, usercode, 
      custcode, MAX(fromdate) AS "Recent",
      CASE WHEN usertype = 1 THEN 'Sales Rep' END AS Salesrep,
      CASE WHEN usertype = 0 THEN 'CSR' END AS CSR
   FROM Original Table
   GROUP BY usercode, custcode, usertype
 ) as Zrad_vw_CSR_0
GROUP BY custcode, Salesrep, CSR;
```

you will eliminate the error, as pointed by @Larnu. But, i think, you don't get desired output.
Try this

```
ALTER VIEW Zrad_vw_CSR AS 
SELECT custcode,
       MIN(Salesrep) Salesrep,
       MIN(CSR) CSR
FROM
 (
   SELECT usertype, usercode, 
      custcode, MAX(fromdate) AS "Recent",
      CASE WHEN usertype = 1 THEN usercode END AS Salesrep,
      CASE WHEN usertype = 0 THEN usercode END AS CSR
   FROM Original Table
   GROUP BY usercode, custcode, usertype
 ) as Zrad_vw_CSR_0
GROUP BY custcode, Salesrep, CSR;
```

Or, shortly

```
ALTER VIEW Zrad_vw_CSR AS 
SELECT custcode,
       MAX(fromdate) AS "Recent",
       min(CASE WHEN usertype = 1 THEN usercode END) AS Salesrep,
       min(CASE WHEN usertype = 0 THEN usercode END) AS CSR
   FROM Original Table
GROUP BY custcode;
```